# How do I set the “all ajax stop” function for multiple ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
xhr = $.ajax;
xhr({
  success: function(){ ajaxProcess = false; },
  beforeSend : function (i) {
    if(ajaxProcess==true)
    xhr.abort();
    else
    ajaxProcess = true;
  }
});

$('.button').click(function(){
  $.getJSON('file.php', function(data){});
};

$('.button2').click(function(){
  $.getJSON('file.php', function(data){});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the global `ajaxSend` handler
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

**EDIT**

To stop all executing requests, you can do something like the following. Create an array of request objects. Then in the the global `ajaxSend` handler you can add the request to the array and do your check. If the check succeeds, iterate through the array and abort all of the requests. Then you can create a global `ajaxStop` handler that removes the requests from the request array as they finish executing.

Comment: How can I stop the running ajax process